# Efficent Dataframe lookup in Apache Spark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to efficiently look up many IDs. What I have is a `dataframe` that looks like this `dataframe` `df_source` but with a couple of million records distributed to 10 Workers:

```
+-------+----------------+
|    URI|     Links_lists|
+-------+----------------+
|  URI_1|[URI_8,URI_9,...|
|  URI_2|[URI_6,URI_7,...|
|  URI_3|[URI_4,URI_1,...|
|  URI_4|[URI_1,URI_5,...|
|  URI_5|[URI_3,URI_2,...|
+-------+----------------+
```

My first step would be to make an `RDD` out of `df_source`:

```
rdd_source = df_source.rdd
```

out of `rdd_source` I want to create an `RDD` that only contains the URIs with IDs. I do this like that:

```
rdd_index = rdd_source.map(lambda x: x[0]).zipWithUniqueId()
```

now I also `.flatMap()` the `rdd_source` in to an `RDD` that contains all relations. Until now only contained within the `Links_list` column.

```
rdd_relations = rdd_source.flatMap(lamda x: x)
```

now I transform both `rdd_index` and `rdd_relations` back into `dataframes` because I want to do joins and I think (I might be wrong on this) joins on `dataframes` are faster.

```
schema_index = StructType([
    StructField("URI", StringType(), True),
    StructField("ID", IntegerType(), True))

df_index = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd_index, schema=schema_index)
```

and

```
schema_relation = StructType([
    StructField("URI", StringType(), True),
    StructField("LINK", StringType(), True))

df_relations = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd_relations, schema=schema_relation )
```

The resulting `dataframes` should look like these two :

```
df_index:
+-------+-------+
|    URI|     ID|
+-------+-------+
|  URI_1|      1|
|  URI_2|      2|
|  URI_3|      3|
|  URI_4|      4|
|  URI_5|      5|
+-------+-------+

df_relations:
+-------+-------+
|    URI|   LINK|
+-------+-------+
|  URI_1|  URI_5|
|  URI_1|  URI_8|
|  URI_1|  URI_9|
|  URI_2|  URI_3|
|  URI_2|  URI_4|
+-------+-------+
```

now to replace the long string URIs in the `df_relations` I will do joins on the `df_index`, the first join:

```
df_relations =\
df_relations.join(df_index, df_relations.URI == df_index.URI,'inner')\
            .select(col(ID).alias(URI_ID),col('LINK'))
```

This should yield me a `dataframe` looking like this:

```
df_relations:
+-------+-------+
| URI_ID|   LINK|
+-------+-------+
|      1|  URI_5|
|      1|  URI_8|
|      1|  URI_9|
|      2|  URI_3|
|      2|  URI_4|
+-------+-------+
```

And the second join:

```
df_relations =\
df_relations.join(df_index, df_relations.LINK == df_index.URI,'inner')\
            .select(col(URI_ID),col('ID').alias(LINK_ID))
```

this should result in the final `dataframe` the one I need. Looking like this

```
df_relations:
+-------+-------+
| URI_ID|LINK_ID|
+-------+-------+
|      1|      5|
|      1|      8|
|      1|      9|
|      2|      3|
|      2|      4|
+-------+-------+
```

where all URIs are replaced with IDs from `df_index`.

Is this the efficent way to look up the IDs for all URIs on both columns in the relation table, or is there a more effective way doing this?

I'm using Apache Spark 2.1.0 with Python 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use RDD for the operations you described. Using RDD can be very costly. Second you do not need to do two joins, you can do just one:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
# add a unique id for each URI
withID = df_source.withColumn("URI_ID", f.monotonically_increasing_id())
# create a single line from each element in the array
exploded = withID.select("URI_ID", f.explode("Links_lists").alias("LINK")
linkID = withID.withColumnRenamed("URI_ID", "LINK_ID").drop("Links_lists")
joined= exploded.join(linkID, on=exploded.LINK==linkID.URI).drop("URI").drop("LINK")
```

Lastly,if linkID  (which is basically df_source with a column replaced) is relatively small (i.e. can be fully contained in a single worker) you can broadcast it. add the following before the join:

```
linkID = f.broadcast(linkID)
```

Comment: That looks very useful I will try it out tomorrow thanks!